# Accessibility Insights only lets me check elements in edge and not in Word (or other app of my choice)

Tags: accessibility-insights

I am trying to inspect Word using the tool but it only highlights elements in Edge. There is no option to choose the target app. I don't see any documentation either. Please help.

Comment: No documentation? [What's this, then?](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/overview/), the following documentation covers how to [inspect elements of any app](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/getstarted/inspect/#select-an-element) or [run tests on any app](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/getstarted/automatedchecks/#running-automated-checks-on-an-entire-app).

If you're asking about the [Accessibility Insights for Web](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/web/overview/) extension for Edge, that is only intended to scan websites and is unable to scan applications.